How can I get the value of specific cases of i into an array or something similar?
I would like to go through each of the Rows then each of the points and capture a value tied to ColNum equaling to each iteration of j then get the max of these values. In easier terms I want to get Width of all object that have attribute ColNum = 2 then get the max of that.
This code is a modified javascript/html for Schneider electric TGML editior.
function load(evt) {
  var TGMLDocument;
  var comp;
  var Point;
  var Row;
  var Row_;
  var colNum;
  var testArr1 = {};
  var testArr2;

  TGMLDocument = evt.getCurrentTarget().getOwnerDocument().getDocumentElement();
  comp = evt.getCurrentTarget();
  Row = nodeFilter(TGMLDocument, "Id", "GlobalRowsX");
  // Point = nodeFilter(comp, "Id", "Point");

  for (var i = 0; i < Row.length; i++) {
    // console.log("The Row is", i);

    Point = nodeFilter(Row[i], "Id", "Point");

    for (var j = 0; j < Point.length; j++) {
      console.log("The Row is " + i + ", The Point is " + j);
      Point[j].setAttribute("ColNum", j);
      console.log("The Column Number is " + Point[j].getAttribute("ColNum"));
    }
  }
}

function nodeFilter(cComp, attrName, attrValue, searchType) {
  try {
    var returnArr = [];
    switch (searchType) {
      case 'children':
        var children = cComp.getChildNodes();
        break;
      case 'nested':
        var children = cComp.getElementsByTagName('*');
        break;
      default:
        var children = cComp.getChildNodes();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      try {
        if (children.item([i]).hasAttribute(attrName)) {
          if (children.item([i]).getAttribute(attrName) == attrValue) {
            returnArr.push(children.item([i]));
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    if (returnArr.length > 1) {
      return returnArr;
    } else if (returnArr.length > 0) {
      return returnArr[0];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch (err) {}
}


I have tried using arrays, obj {}, and eval to create dynamic variables declarations.
Row and Point are returned as arrays.

Your nodeFilter() function looks like you could replace it with a simple call to row[i].getElementById("Point").

But IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't have multiple id="Point".

What is the problem you're having?

Please post a [mcve]. You can use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds like a job for Array.reduce. Please edit to include a minimal example of the data format, and then it should be easier to understand.

Unfortunately, since this is TGML and not java/html I cannot make it executable. Node filter is a function made by someone else that puts all objects with the like ID in an array that I use to sort columns on the graphic.
